# Installation options for an electric dryer

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, dryer

I just bought a house with a gas hookup for the dryer, but did not realize that when purchasing an electric dryer.

The builder says the laundry room was built for a gas dryer after purchasing the electrical one.

At this point we may not be able to return it what can i do and how much would it cost?

Comment: We don't do pricing/costing questions here, since that data tends to be localized and changes over time, causing any answers to become wrong.  Wiring costs are also *very* particular to the house's construction along the route required, as well as whether the service panel is already full.   Figure probably starts at $150, cost of getting an electrician to come out.

Comment: If main panel is in or next to laundry room, easy/inexpensive. If it is on a different floor (common in many newer houses) then it gets **much** more expensive. Switching always costs a bunch. I contemplated switching from electric to gas (gas already in the room for furnace/water heater/feed to kitchen) and decided the payback in energy savings would be several years and didn't bother. You go with the connections you have unless a really good reason to switch.

Comment: I did the opposite thing about 25 years ago, and the cost was low. The contractor put in electric and I wanted gas because it is cheaper . The sub contractor ran several feet of gas pipe from the nearby water heater  ; I don't even remember if there was a charge. Now there are both and everybody is happy..

Comment: I can't imagine you getting an electrician out there to run a 240 Volt dryer circuit for less than $500  and that's if he/she really liked you. Not sure where you bought the dryer from but it seems that if you talked to them about  an exchange for a gas dryer, they'd probably go for it.  Had a similar problem down here where the individuals put an add in the local paper or condo bulletin board and sold the dryer and then just bought the type they needed.

Comment: @JACK The devil is in the details. I'd bet in my house if I had gas and needed the 240V it would be $200 or less - because everything is "right there" (provided there was space in the panel...) But if it has to go to another floor through finished walls/ceiling...yeah, $500.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  You are so right about the details. In all my years I don't think I ever ran into a case where everything was "right there".  Being from Chicago, I was thinking  EMT.

Answer (score 4):

If i assume correctly you do not have a 220v outlet for your electric drier.

The most economical thing to do is **Sell the electric drier and buy a gas drier**. You may loose a little money selling it but it will likely be  more of a loss/expense to pay to have a new outlet installed.

The gas drier is (*probably*) going to have a lower energy cost to operate and the cost of Having an electrician install a 220v drier outlet  MAY be a significant expense. (*for a variety of reasons*)

We can not tell you what it would cost, you can get an electrician to give your an estimate to find out.

Comment: Installing a 240v circuit for the dryer is NOT a DIY. Selling the electric dryer for the gas IS. Right off the bat you can estimate what that costs.